# How do I solve VBA error 9 - out of range?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I found some code on how to copy and paste a tablet from Excel to PPT, but I keep running into the error 9 'out of range'. It's my first time working with VBA, so I'm not too sure how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ExporttoPPT()

Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim slde As PowerPoint.slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.shape
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim chrt As ChartObject

Dim vSheet$
Dim vRange$
Dim vChart$
Dim vWidth As Double
Dim vHeight As Double
Dim vTop As Double
Dim vLeft As Double
Dim vSlide_No As Long
Dim ShpCount As Integer
Dim expRng As Range
Dim expChart As ChartObjects

Dim adminSh As Worksheet
Dim configRng As Range
Dim configChart As Range
Dim xlfile$
Dim pptfile$

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set adminSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")
Set configRng = adminSh.Range("Rng_Sheets")
Set configChart = adminSh.Range("Chart_Sheets")

xlfile = adminSh.[excelPth]
pptfile = adminSh.[pptPth]

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xlfile)
Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile, msoFalse)

For Each rng In configRng
    With adminSh
        vSheet$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
        vRange$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 7).Value
        vWidth = .Cells(rng.Row, 8).Value
        vHeight = .Cells(rng.Row, 9).Value
        vTop = .Cells(rng.Row, 10).Value
        vLeft = .Cells(rng.Row, 11).Value
        vSlide_No = .Cells(rng.Row, 12).Value
    End With
    
    wb.Activate
    Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
    Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
    expRng.Copy
    
    Set slde = pre.Slides(vSlide_No)
    slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue
    
    ShpCount = slde.Shapes.Count
    
    Set shp = slde.Shapes(ShpCount)
   
    With shp
        .Top = vTop
        .Left = vLeft
        .Width = vWidth
        .Height = vHeight
    End With
    
    Set shp = Nothing
    Set slde = Nothing
    Set expRng = Nothing
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set expRng = Nothing

Next rng

pre.Save
pre.Close

Set pre = Nothing
Set ppt_app = Nothing

wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The VBA debugger says it is to do with the following line:

```
Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!!!
Thank you!
Oliver

```
wb.Activate
Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
expRng.Copy

Set slde = pre.Slides(vSlide_No)
slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue
```

Comment: Do you have a tab, in your active workbook, named for the value in the vSheet$ variable ?

Comment: @SpectralInstance yea I do, and the type is a String

Comment: Ok, if you click on Debug when the error occurs, what happens if you execute that line in the Immediate Window ?

Comment: So if I execute line by line with F8, I can continue running the code until this line:
```    slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue ```

And then the error 9 occurs.

When I hit Debug, it highlights:
``` Sheets(vSheet$).Activate ```

Comment: You have that line twice (as well as the Activate one) in your code - please edit your code with comments so that I can be clear about which is causing the error

Comment: Does that make it clearer?

Comment: If I understand correctly - you're saying that the line generates an error in the _second_ iteration of the loop?
I'd also consider adding a DoEvents call after the PasteSpecial line, since pasting into other apps can be 'time consuming'

Comment: Actually, I think I may figured it out. My "range" that I was looping had an extra empty cell at the bottom, so that's probably why its not picking up anything. But now I have other bugs later in my code. I'll try look into that now. Thanks heaps @SpectralInstance!!!

Answer (score 0):

May not fix your problem but here's a refactored version combining your two loops into one.  Missing any error checking such as ensuring worksheets/chartobjects etc actually exist before trying to access them.

```vb
'Declare a Type to hold the various configuration details for a copy/paste/move/size step
'All config is stored in one table with columns as indicated below
Type Settings
    Type As String    'need one new column in your table for this
    Sheet As String   'source worksheet
    Source As String  'range address or chartobject name
    Width As Double   'settings for sizing/location...
    Height As Double
    Top As Double
    Left As Double
    Slide As Long     'destination slide index
End Type

Sub ExporttoPPT()

    Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation, ws As Worksheet
    Dim config As Settings, wb As Workbook, adminSh As Workbook, configRng As Range, rw As Range
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set adminSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")
    Set rw = adminSh.Range("SettingsRow1") '<< first row of settings in the config table
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(adminSh.[excelPth])
    Set pres = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(adminSh.[pptPth], msoFalse)

    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0 'loop each row in the config table while not blank
        config = GetSettings(rw)     'get the configuration from this row
        
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(config.Sheet)
        
        With pres.Slides(config.Slide)   'destination slide
        
            Select Case config.Type      'what kind of thing are we copying?
                Case "Range"
                    ws.Range(config.Source).Copy
                    .Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue
                Case "Chart"
                    ws.ChartObjects(config.Source).Copy 'or eg CopyPicture
                    .Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue
            End Select
            
            With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)  'position and size the pasted shape
                .Top = config.Top
                .Left = config.Left
                .Width = config.Width
                .Height = config.Height
            End With
        End With
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    
    'clean up
    pres.Save
    pres.Close
    ppt_app.Quit
    wb.Close False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

'populate and return a `Settings` variable from a row
Function GetSettings(rw As Range) As Settings
    Dim rv As Settings
    rv.Type = rw.Cells(1).Value
    rv.Sheet = rw.Cells(2).Value
    rv.Source = rw.Cells(3).Value
    rv.Width = rw.Cells(4).Value
    rv.Height = rw.Cells(5).Value
    rv.Top = rw.Cells(6).Value
    rv.Left = rw.Cells(7).Value
    rv.Slide = rw.Cells(8).Value
    GetSettings = rv
End Function
```

Comment: That coding is amazingly beautiful!!! Thank you so much Tim!!! There's just one problem that I've been encountering when I use the ppPasteOLEObject command for a chart is: "Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable.

Comment: Also is there a way to end the loop once the "Settings" range incurs a blank space? So that the runtime/debug error doesn't occur. In essence, I'm hoping to add more objects without having to adjust the "Settings" range every single time.

Comment: Added a few edits to process config rows until a blank one is found.  I would maybe try a different paste setting (or use `CopyPicture` in Excel if you don't need "live" plots)

Comment: Thank you Tim! I've tried implementing the new Do While Loop, but it gives me a "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: Is there a way to do different paste commands for different "type" within the same loop? For example ranges paste as OLEObject and charts as JPG?

Comment: You can move the `Select Case` inside the `With pres.Slides(config.Slide)` block and select different cop/paste methods depending on the type of source object - see edit above.  As for the "Run-time error 5" you'd need to provide a bit more detail there.

Comment: The run-time error 5 occurs on this line: `Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0`

Comment: When that happens what is `rw.address`?

Comment: Does that mean the value in the Locals? It has Value: nothing and Type: Range

Comment: Should not be Nothing if this line above ran: `Set rw = adminSh.Range("SettingsRow1")`  "SettingsRow1" should be a named range pointing to the first row in the table of copy/paste configuration details.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back to you Tim. Had to restart my computer. Its working perfectly now thank you!!! You have been amazing, really appreciate all the support you've given me.